# ScriptApp.getUserTriggers give server error if a manually added installed trigger exists

Tags: google-apps-script

The call works fine normally, but if there are manually added installable triggers then it fails with this error:

> We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 6, file "Code")

I tried on a blank file, in both the paid and free account. See here:

https://www.screencast.com/t/3NUvQema

Comment: Seems like you should file a bug report. Stack Overflow is not Google Support.

Comment: I will, thanks. But I am trying to confirming that I am not missing something first. Google's authorisation system is kind of complicated.